# How to add 32bit SWT libraries instead of 64bit ones in eclipse 4 RCP plugin project?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, libs

I have 64bit Windows, 64 bit eclipse and both 32 and 64 bit jre installed.

What I want to do: I have some 32bit process, to which I want to attach a GUI made in e4. My eclipse is fully configured (not by me) for 64bit development and it is critical not to reconfigure it as much as possible (there is like a standard build, widely used in firma).

Now, let's assume I create a dummy eclipse 4 RCP project, which of course uses SWT libraries. If I run it on 32 bit jre, I will receive an error: "can't load a 64 bit SWT libraries on 32 bit jvm". Fully expectable.

Now the question. I've downloaded 32 bit SWT libraries, the swt-4.9-win32-win32-x86.zip file contains swt.jar and src.zip. I have obviously 64 bit STW libraries in eclipse plugins folder. What **exactly**, step-by-step, I need to do in my plugin project in order to run it on 32 bit jre? Sorry, I'm a bit newbie in plugin development in eclipse and I don't know how to "simply replace 64 bit versions with 32 bit ones".

P.S the variant "just run everything on 64 bit jvm" is impossible, since this process loads 32bit native libs.

Comment: And why not simply use a 32-bit version of eclipse?

Comment: You need to use a complete target platform with a 32 bit version of Eclipse (2018-09 was the last 32 bit release)

Comment: @greg-449 good, that you mentioned it, because I forgot about this in OP post. Actually my TP is self-defined and restricted to the certain necessities, which are met by this 32 java-process (to be more precise: there are plugins in repositories, that are loaded via target platform and shouldn't be stored locally). So my question: could I just add this 32bit target platform as a, let's say, separate folder to my current active target platform? And isn't this TP just a plugins folder in eclipse?

Comment: I couldn't install 32 bit eclipse, because we have an own build of eclipse in the firma and all software should be developed on this certain build, which is 64 bit. A variant of adding some folder to the TP is possible, to change the whole eclipse environment - sadly not

Comment: Note that the complete RCP has to be 32 bit if you want to use a 32 bit SWT, you can't have part 32 and part 64. You can have a target platform which contains 32 bit and 64 bit (but only up to Eclipse 2018-09) and the build will select all 32 bit or all 64 bit.

Comment: @greg-449 so it is not possible just to, simply speaking, download some .jar files, replace something, so that in the same eclipse environment SWT libraries will be now changed from 64 to 32 bits? Do I understand you correctly?

Comment: No you can't do that, some plug-in names are different. The exe which launches the RCP is also either 32 bit or 64 bit. Versions of Eclipse after 2018-09 do not support 32 bit at all.

Comment: @greg-449 so the only option is to switch either to 32bit eclipse or eclipse 2018-09? In all other ways it is impossible somehow to run a RCP project while using 64 bit eclipse but 32 bit jre, right? Okay, sad news, but many thanks for clarifying this question.